# Operator invalid for class types

Tags: java, arguments

I want to add a pokemon type (name + number) to a binary search tree. Here's my BinarySearchClass.

```
public void insert(Pokemon n) { // n is data/key
    Node newNode = new Node(n);
    if (root == null) { // empty tree
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node current = root;
        Node parent = null;
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            parent = current;
            if (n < current.data) {
                current = current.left;
                if (current == null) {
                    parent.left = newNode;
                    flag = false;
                }
            } // if( n < current.data)
            else {
                current = current.right;
                if (current == null) {
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    flag = false;
                } // current == null}
            } // else}
        } // while(flag)
    } // root != null
}
```

The error I get is at the n < current.data. I can't make it so it just compares the number of Pokemon, such as Kadabra 64, or Bulbsaur 1, but also use entire Pokemon type. Do I have to use getNumber() in my Pokemon constructor class?
Using this testDriver code:

```
    BinarySearchTree T = new BinarySearchTree();
    for (int i = 0; i < userNumber; i++){
        T.insert(poke[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `<` is an operator used to compare numbers. A Pokemon is not a number. Maybe you want n.getNumber() < current.data.getNumber()?

Comment: YESS!! Thank you so much! That was stupid of me.

Comment: This is why meaningful variable names are a good idea.  `n` is traditionally a numeric value in algebra.  Personally, I would have defined the method signature as `public void insert(Pokemon pokemon)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with

```
n < current.data
```

is that *n* is not a primitive type variable. It represents a `Pokemon` object. And thing is: Java does **not** support operator overloading for reference types.

What would work:

```
n.someNumericalField < current.data
```

(assuming that current.data would also represent some primitive type )

Or maybe

```
n.lessThan(current.data)
```

(where `lessThan()` would be a method that *you* implement within your Pokemon class)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a `Pokemon` with a data. You need to do something like:

```
//assuming that n.data is an integer or other comparable value
if (n.data < current.data)
```